# validation errors than can cause problems

Tags: magento2.3.1

> vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Observer/PickupEmailObserver.php

What happen if `$transport` is null ? 
see line 93

```
$order = $transport->getData('order');
```

> /magento/module-sales/Model/OrderRepository.php

What happen if `$order->getPayment()` return null ?
see line

```
$paymentAdditionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Off course `$order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation()` throw error when `$order->getPayment() return null`.

If you want to resolve this then rewrite the class `Temando\Shipping\Observer\`PickupEmailObserver` and   if put a condition like

```
if($order!== null){
$paymentAdditionalInformation = $order->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation();
}
```